# How to convert a square SVG to all-size ICO?

Tags: inkscape, icon, svg, favicon

I've drawn an icon in InkScape and would like to export it to an ICO file that would include sprites for all the reasonable resolutions (16x16, 32x32, ... 256x256 etc). How can this be done (without using huge and expensive software like Photoshop, CorelDraw etc)?

Comment: A quick search tells me there is no way to export even a single ICO out of InkScape, but there are lots of suggestions on how to do so with additional - free - software such as GIMP. Did you check those options? If they did not work for you, can you tell why not?

Comment: @RadLexus what I have tried is a number of online tools and all of them, as far as I could understand, mean to create single-size ICOns.

Comment: So you want to know how to create multiple-size ICOs? Try the options in this Stack Overflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354617/how-to-make-get-a-multi-size-ico-file (again, found by a simple Google query...).

Comment: There is an [Inkscape extension](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Extension_repository#Icon_Generation) which seems to [export as ico](https://bitbucket.org/daviddamerell/inkscapesaveasicoextension) file, but I have no time at the moment to try if it works.

Comment: If you've found any of the below to answer your question please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: As of 2019, there is no need to create .ico files from .svg as GUI frameworks [support SVG natively](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3526366/774575), from a file, even from a shape created internally.

Comment: Consider looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69487280/7585517) to a similar question

Answer (score 74, accepted):

A command line solution:

1. Export your SVG `master.svg` to PNG with Inkscape:

```bash
# Install on Ubuntu
sudo apt-get install inkscape
# Other systems: make sure Inkscape is in your PATH

inkscape -w 16 -h 16 -o 16.png master.svg
inkscape -w 32 -h 32 -o 32.png master.svg
inkscape -w 48 -h 48 -o 48.png master.svg
```

2. Convert the PNG images to ICO with ImageMagick:

```bash
# Install on Ubuntu
sudo apt-get install imagemagick

convert 16.png 32.png 48.png icon.ico
```

3. Optional - Make sure your ICO contains everything:

```bash
$ identify icon.ico
icon.ico[1] ICO 16x16 16x16+0+0 32-bit sRGB 21.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
icon.ico[0] ICO 32x32 32x32+0+0 32-bit sRGB 21.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
icon.ico[0] ICO 48x48 48x48+0+0 32-bit sRGB 21.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Comment: You can also use a simple batch or shell file in order to simplify the work.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better (even if a little more complicated) to export the many png sizes directly from SVG instead of resizing already rasterized PNGs?

Comment: Just in case anyone else is curious, the "..." is not literal. It represents other png file sizes to cram into the favicon.ico file.

Comment: @Nostalg.io Good remark, thanks! I edited the answer.

Comment: @heltonbiker Yes, you're right. SVG maintains resolution & quality when resized; png does not.

Comment: @HunterS That's right! With a twist: ImageMagick sometimes produces poor results when processing SVG. This is why my reworked answer is using command line Inkscape for this particular task.

Comment: @philippe_b Perhaps I misunderstood the comment I replied to.. or perhaps my reply was too open to interpretation... or maybe I'm not understanding your reply...? I was implying that using inkscape to resize the svg and then export to png is the best way to get different sizes and then using imagick as you mentioned to generate the icon from png files. Is this correct? .... either way, I had no clue that imagick had issues with SVG, so thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: As of 2020 (if not sooner) the -e option is now -o

Comment: According to [some random site I found](https://www.emergeinteractive.com/insights/detail/the-essentials-of-favicons/), a recommended size list for modern (2022) situations would be 32x32, 128x128, 180x180 and 192x192.  There are, sadly, various other possible sizes that may be useful to some, and, as far as I can tell, no standard for it.  On the upside, browser support for svg-based favicons seems to be increasing??  Though not necessarily fully there yet.

Answer (score 47):

You can use [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) right away:

```
convert -density 384 icon.svg -define icon:auto-resize icon.ico
```

[Edit]

Since ImageMagick version 7, you need to add `magick` in front of the command (see [doc on CLI](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php)), so the command line is now:

```
magick -density 384 icon.svg -define icon:auto-resize icon.ico
```

You can also check this answer for more information:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16922387/1603480

Comment: Why that density?

Comment: I don't know, I just copy-pasted this from elsewhere.

Comment: @naught101 here's the documentation for the density flag - although, it seems like it's a rather unnecessary step unless you're doing something very specific with image sizes, dpi's, and the intermediate image rasterization thereof. https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#density

Comment: Use `convert -background none icon.svg -define icon:auto-resize icon.ico` to keep transparent background.

Comment: `magick convert -background none icon.svg -define icon:auto-resize icon.ico` worked for me.

Comment: Why that density? Because someone in a forum did the this math: `256*72/48=384`. So, that density number is totally arbitrary. Source: https://gist.github.com/azam/3b6995a29b9f079282f3 which pointed me to http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=25406#p110244 Proper documentation: https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#density Alternative solution: https://superuser.com/a/489231

Answer (score 10):

Bash version...

```
#!/bin/bash

set -ex

svg=$1

size=(16 32 24 48 72 96 144 152 192 196)

out="$(mkdir -d)"

echo Making bitmaps from your svg...

for i in ${size[@]}; do
  inkscape $svg --export-png="$out/$i.png" -w$i -h$i --without-gui
done

echo Compressing...

## Replace with your favorite (e.g. pngquant)
# optipng -o7 "$out/*.png"
pngquant -f --ext .png "$out/*.png" --posterize 4 --speed 1

echo Converting to favicon.ico...

convert "$out/*.png" favicon.ico

# Clean-up
rm -rf "$out/"

echo Done
```

Usage:
`./favicon.sh your-square-svg-file.svg`

Requires:
inkscape imagemagick optipng (optional)
from your package manager.

I found it easier to re-create this for the bash shell since Win10 and Inkscape weren't getting along. This was tested within Windows Subsystem for Linux but it should also work on Mac.

Used this reference to choose the sizes I cared about: https://github.com/audreyr/favicon-cheat-sheet. Adjust the `size` array to your specific needs.

Comment: Note: `--export-png=` is deprected.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest this approach:

1) create a script to export the SVG to any required size. I've coded this .bat script to help me create an Android icon

```
@echo off
set file="%~f1"
set path=%~dp1
set inkscape="C:\Program Files\Inkscape\inkscape.exe"

echo Le icone saranno salvate in %path%
echo Produzione icone applicative

echo %file% --export-png="%path%/ic32.png" -w32 -h32 > %~dp1/commands.txt
echo %file% --export-png="%path%/ic48.png" -w48 -h48 > %~dp1/commands.txt
echo %file% --export-png="%path%/ic72.png" -w72 -h72 > %~dp1/commands.txt
echo %file% --export-png="%path%/ic96.png" -w96 -h96 > %~dp1/commands.txt
echo %file% --export-png="%path%/ic144.png" -w144 -h144 > %~dp1/commands.txt
echo %file% --export-png="%path%/ic192.png" -w192 -h192 > %~dp1/commands.txt
echo %file% --export-png="%path%/ic512.png" -w512 -h512 > %~dp1/commands.txt
%inkscape% --shell < %~dp1/commands.txt
erase "%~dp1/commands.txt"

echo Procedura terminata
```

**NOTE**:

- the defined **%inkscape%** var should be adequate to your Inkscape install path
- the script echoes all export commands to a temp file to a better management of inkscape process. The "shell" cli param accepts more commands using a single instance instead of spawn an instance per command.

> With this parameter, Inkscape will enter an interactive command line shell mode. In this mode, you type in commands at the prompt and Inkscape executes them, without you having to run a new copy of Inkscape for each command. This feature is mostly useful for scripting and server uses: it adds no new capabilities but allows you to improve the speed and memory requirements of any script that repeatedly calls Inkscape to perform command line tasks (such as export or conversions). Each command in shell mode must be a complete valid Inkscape command line but without the Inkscape program name, for example "file.svg --export-pdf=file.pdf". ([see inkscape manual](https://inkscape.org/sk/doc/inkscape-man.html))

2) Add to the above script the convert syntax stated in [philippe-b answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/77466/112935) which merges all the generated PNGs to a single ICO file

3) Optionally, remove all exported PNGs as they are no more needed

Answer (score 5):

This website is my go to for favicon generation as it includes the icons for the Add To Homescreen for most devices (Windows, macOS, Android, iOS)
https://realfavicongenerator.net/

Comment: This answer should be WAY higher up. Instead of making a lot of fuss about technical details and scripts and whatnot, this answer cuts to the essentials and gets the result done. Bravo! Have my upvote.

Comment: Great resource and this is an excellent solution. Well done!

Answer (score 3):

Required tools: inkscape and gimp

1. inkscape: export your svg to a png 64x64.
2. gimp: create a new project with a transparent background and layer size of 64x64 and import the png image to the layer.
3. duplicate the layer, go to "Layer" > "Scale layer" > choose 32x32
4. duplicate the last layer again and repeat the scaling for 16x16, 8x8
5. export the image to .ico and you will see all layers that will be embedded in the single .ico file. (make sure you don't have empty layers)

Comment: An option would be to create the icons in Inkscape. Open the SVGs in Gimp and save as .ico.

Answer (score 3):

To convert SVG to ICO file, you can use: https://redketchup.io/icon-editor and the option: "Create Icon from Image".

Comment: thank you! it can also export icon as png

Comment: this is the way, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution of `@pillippe_b` wrapped into one BASH function:

```bash
function svg2ico {
  basename=${1%.svg}
  inkscape -w 16 -h 16 -e "$basename_16.png" "$1"
  inkscape -w 32 -h 32 -e "$basename_32.png" "$1"
  inkscape -w 48 -h 48 -e "$basename_48.png" "$1"
  convert -verbose "$basename_16.png" "$basename_32.png" "$basename_48.png" "$basename.ico"
}
```

Only the resulting `.ico` file remains. This requires Inkscape and ImageMagick be installed:

```bash
sudo apt-get install inkscape imagemagick
```

Answer (score 0):

While most online tools failed this task (and converted to a single resolution .ico), I just came across one that worked fine: https://anyconv.com/svg-to-ico-converter/

It converted my .svg file into an .ico with 9 different resolutions, from 16x16 up to 256x256.

Answer (score 0):

Inkscape is nice but I already have it on Windows and it would eat a up a lot of extra space on my [WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) environment. Thanks to the [previous tip](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/102010/167542) which I upvoted, I used [Imagemagick convert](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) directly, to resize to different resolutions from e.g. `source.svg` on the command line:

```
convert -resize 16x16 -background none source.svg 16.ico
convert -resize 32x32 -background none source.svg 32.ico
```

Which is also simple enough to script. Note that this includes one resolution only. As per the [accepted answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/77466/167542), for multiple resolutions you can `convert` to several *png* files first and then combine them all, e.g. `convert 16.png 32.png 48.png 64.png 128.png favicon.ico`.

It is necessary to use [-background none](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#background) because the default is white "if none is specified or found in the image". Of course, remove it, if you do actually have a background to keep.

It is pretty cool to be able to use `convert` to do things like precisely resize a JPG image while converting it to PNG, using a similar command to above.

For example:

```
convert -resize 700 path/to/original.jpg path/to/resized.jpg
```

Will resize *original.jpg* to a width of 700 pixels, while keeping the aspect ratio, into a new file *resized.jpg*. One of the most intuitive command-line tools I've used!